# how to calculate values in multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have a multidimentional array and i want to sum all the values with the name total here is an example

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 829
        [tok] => f3404ba92a40f7
        [user_id] => 1
        [total] => 10000
        [created_at] => 2020-12-03 00:18:09
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 830
        [tok] => 2669483afacc47
        [user_id] => 1
        [total] => 2000
        [created_at] => 2020-12-03 00:18:12
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 831
        [tok] => 9b72ba6ab4d8d0
        [user_id] => 1
        [total] => 5000
        [created_at] => 2020-12-03 00:18:14
    )
```

I want to sum all totals in the array

Comment: SO isn't a free code-writing service. Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Just change `$data` for your variable name.

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $sum += $row['total'];
}

echo $sum; // 17000
```